# Date Picker edition of fields

Tags: android, datepicker

Is it possible to disable the edition of fields in `DatePicker`? Indeed when I touch on the editable box in the `DatePicker`, the keyboard
appears, and I don't want this.

Someone have an idea?

Thanks a lot for your response :)

Comment: It's a date *picker* - letting you *pick* dates... are you trying to use it just to *display* dates?

Comment: no i mean to say that i can change the date by using - sign present in date picker,But when I touch on the editable box in the DatePicker i dont want the keyboard to display...

Comment: Okay, so you only want editing by touch. That's not quite the same as saying you don't want it to be editable (which is what I assume you mean by "edition"). I suggest you edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh i got the answer..the thing we need to do is...

```
    DatePicker m_dtPicker  = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dt_picker);
    setDisabledTextViews(m_dtPicker);


    private void setDisabledTextViews(ViewGroup dp) 
    {
        for (int x = 0, n = dp.getChildCount(); x < n; x++) 
        {
            View v = dp.getChildAt(x);

            if (v instanceof TextView) 
            {
                v.setEnabled(false);
            } 
            else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) 
            {
                 setDisabledTextViews((ViewGroup)v);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually really easy. Just use

```
datePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

The NumberPickers will never receive the focus when they are tapped and the soft input keyboard should not appear. I have been using this method on API level 7 with success.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be done. DatePicker has that functionality specifically to allow users convenient option instead of tapping/holding +/-

What you are trying to achieve is the iOS for of Picker which although looks nice but really is inconvenient on Android.